# IFS in .ksh acting strangly

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh, vi

Can someone please explain why my IFS statement is replacing my characters in my output file? What do I need to change in order to solve it? I want to read an input file line by line (record by record) and the IFS to be ignored completely, but I am not sure what to put so that I get out what i put in.

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS='\n'
record="The rain in Spain"
record2="c:\user\user\document.txt"
echo $record
echo $record
```

My output is replacing all my lower case 'n' characters with a space and my '\' characters are being deleted, instead of (what i thought would happen) separating by a new line:

```
The rai  i  Spai
c: user user docume t.txt
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

That's not a [literal newline](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) - your field separators are literally the characters `\` (backslash) and `n`. You can use this:

```
IFS='
'
```

or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638127/ifs-in-ksh-acting-strangly/38638200?noredirect=1#comment64659393_38638200):

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

Comment: `ksh` also supports ANSI-C quoting: `IFS=$'\n'`.

Comment: Thanks. What are you doing there? is that ' followed by a new line and then another ' ? I'm confused why they're on separate lines.

Comment: chepner - Thanks, that is actually what i had originally, when it caused the problem (i'm retyping everything because my actual script is on a testing machine not connected to anything else inc. internet and i forgot the $.